# VB 13 windows form - how do I pass my variable between two forms [New to coding]

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, parameters, parameter-passing

On one form I have:

```
lblQuizName.Text = "Enter Quiz Name"
```

Later on I call a separate form:

```
frmQuizForStudents.Show()
```

How do I move the text from `lblQuizName.Text` into this form as it doesn't let me write a parameter when I call `frmQuizForStudents`.

Especially because it has `Public Class frmQuizForStudents` at the top, I cannot write: "`Public Class frmQuizForStudents(lblQuizName)`".

Comment: [Ask Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=how+do+I+pass+my+variable+between+two+forms+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Ly8bWKHYGIvb8AeyyJewCg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new constructor using the parameter needed for your `frmQuizForStudents` form :

```
Public Class frmQuizForStudents

    sub new(QuizName as string)
         '... Code here
    end sub

end class
```

Also, to call this Form you will need to create a new instance of it before using the new parameter:

```
dim NewQuizForStudents as New frmQuizForStudents(lblQuizName.Text)
NewQuizForStudents.show
```